# Performance improvement when comparing 2 huge csv files [python]

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have 2 csv files and I need to test every row in the first file against all the rows in the other file and write matching row to a new csv file. Here is the file structure.

**csv 1** (Has readings which are sampled 20s apart. First row is always header):

Date Time Col1 Col2
6/27/16 17:28:21 21 3244
6/27/16 17:28:41 21 3278
6/27/16 17:29:01 21 3299

**csv 2** (Has readings which are sampled 1s apart.No header):

6/27/16 17:28:21 3245
6/27/16 17:28:22 3266
6/27/16 17:28:23 3277

I compare the timestamps from csv1 and csv2 and upon match, I create a output row containing csv1 row plus the 2nd column reading from csv2. A sample row in the output csv file would be:

Date Time Col1 Col2 Col3
6/27/16 17:28:21 21 3244 3245

Here is my python code that does this:

```
    with open("file1.csv",'r') as csv1:  
             with open("out.csv", 'w') as myoutput:
             writer = csv.writer(myoutput)
             row_count=0
             headerSet=0
             for row in csv.reader(csv1):
                 with open ("file2.csv",'r') as csv2:
                     in2 = csv.reader(csv2)
                     for mrow in in2:
                        if row_count == 0 and headerSet==0:
                            # Generate Header Row for the output csv file
                            writer.writerow(row+["Col3"]) 
                            headerSet=1
                        else:
                            # Code to fetch timestamp from csv1 and csv2
                            if csv1_ts == csv2_ts:
                                # Fetch 2nd column value from csv2
                                val=mrow[1]
                                writer.writerow(row+[val])
                                break
                     else:
                        continue
                     row_count += 1
```

The code seems to take a lot of time for generating the output csv file. What can I do to improve the performance of this code and speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that rows are ordered by time you could initially read a row from both files. If timestamp of the rows match then write the row to output and advance to next row in both files. If timestamps differ then read the next row from file where current timestamp was smaller. Below is simple implementation of the code in action:

```
import csv

def get_key(row):
    date = [int(x) for x in row[0].split('/')]
    date[0], date[2] = date[2], date[0]
    return date, row[1]

with open('file1.csv') as csv1, open('file2.csv') as csv2, open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    csv1 = csv.reader(csv1)
    csv2 = csv.reader(csv2)
    out = csv.writer(out)

    # Header
    out.writerow(next(csv1) + ['Col3'])
    row1 = next(csv1, None)
    row2 = next(csv2, None)

    while row1 and row2:
        key1 = get_key(row1)
        key2 = get_key(row2)
        if key1 < key2:
            row1 = next(csv1, None)
        elif key1 > key2:
            row2 = next(csv2, None)
        else:
            out.writerow(row1 + row2[-1:])
            row1 = next(csv1, None)
            row2 = next(csv2, None)
```